# Linear Differential Difference Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, finite-differences

I am interested in solving the following equation: 
$$ W'(s) = \big( W(s) - W(s-1) \big)\cdot \lambda$$
where $W(s)=e^s$ for $s \leq 1.$

This might be quite simple yet when I searched for 'linear differential-difference equations' and for 'mixed differential-difference equations' I was able to find specific articles dealing with methods for general differential equations. I have found an article studying approximate solutions for these yet aren't there elementary methods for finding solutions explicitly?

Any references are appreciated.

Comment: If you know that $W(s)= e^s$, what you trying to solve for? $\lambda$?  If that is the case, this is not a differential or finite difference equation. It is just a basic algebra problem (other than knowing how to differentiate $e^s$).

Comment: There are very few examples where you get explicit solutions. You can always try the method of steps, but it usually gets messy pretty fast. To do it note that for $1<s<2$ you have ordinary linear ODE. Solve it. Do the same for $2<s<3$, etc.

Comment: @PaulSinclair it is an example of a delay differential equation where the initial condition is a function on the interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Artem - I don't seem to recall asking about what kind of differential equation this was an example of.

Comment: @PaulSinclair You stated (incorrectly) that this is (citation) "...this is not a differential..." And three people somehow found this (incorrect) remark useful. So, in an ideal world it would be great if you edit your (incorrect) comment.

Comment: @Artem - If you will please read my comment again, this time with a little more care, you will note that I said it is not a differential equation *if the variable being solved for is* $\lambda$. If $W$ were the unknown, then this indeed would be a differential equation. But since $W$ is a known function, it is not. $s$ is treated as a ranging variable, which leaves $\lambda$ as the most likely candidate for a variable to be solved for, Since $\lambda$ is not differentiated, this is not a differential equation in $\lambda$.

Comment: Yes, of course I knew that we do not live in an ideal world. Though every time it is a disappointment again. @PaulSinclair The question contains a title. This is not a universal, but still very frequent name for functional differential equations.Moreover, the question clearly include the condition $s\leq 1$. Anyone who saw these equations before should recognize one. You did not. So now please be sure that the unknown function there is $W$ for $s>1$.

Comment: @Artem - please read the OP. Note that immediately after given the differential equation, it clearly states that $W(s) = e^s$. Therefore $W(s)$ is *not* unknown. I recognized the equation. But you failed to recognize that the problem is apparently *not* about finding $W(s)$. So I posted a comment asking what the question is about, and adding that if it is about finding $\lambda$ - the variable not defined in the question - then it is not a differential equation, since the *unknown* in that case (note the "if this is the case" in my comment) is not diffentiated.